# How to add a title to a d3.js radar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I add a title to the following radar chart:

[D3.js - Radar Chart or Spider Chart - Adjusted from radar-chart-d3](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614)

I tried adding a `.text("Sample Title Here");` but that didn't work. Also not sure where to add it.

Comment: looks like title is already there.  If you look at this node you will see title class to it "What % of owners use a specific service in a week". thiis node is the title in radar chart

Comment: So you just need to edit that text from the example code

Comment: Oh thanks, thought that was a legend header. Would it be possible to center it, increase font and possibly bold it?